# Does anyone know of a package for typesetting Timelord?

Tags: fonts

You know, Doctor Who. I figure if we've got Tengwar and Sindarin, we've probably got Timelord (specifically [Circular Gallifreyan](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Gallifreyan_(language))). Anyone?

Comment: You could probably just [download it](http://ufonts.com/fonts/cctimelord-solid.html) and use XeLaTeX...

Comment: ... or use LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Do you want [the script called „Timelord“](http://ufonts.com/fonts/cctimelord-solid.html) or the Timelord symbols known as [Gallifreyan](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Gallifreyan_(language)), and which version of the five (known) ones?

Comment: Oh, wow, I'm not as big of a Whovian as I thought! I want Circular Gallifreyan. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: KIDNEYS! I'VE GOT NEW KIDNEYS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for the simple reason that the sentence structure is not linear.

In general (and this is also how TeX works), fonts contain a bunch of *symbols* that are extracted from the font and placed in *a line* to form a sentence. The only adjustments made are *horizontal* kerning - moving the symbols left or right, depending on neighbouring symbols.

[Circular Gallifreyan](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Gallifreyan_(language)) is, well, circular and therefore not linear. Adjustments are made horizontally *and* vertically, together with rotation. The following is a *word* - a circle of symbols:

[image]

The following is a *sentence* (a circle of circular symbols):

[image]

The symbol/word/sentence structure of this "language" is more of an art form than what we commonly see in the recti-linear world of writing. You are most likely going to be forced to *draw* these words/sentences using a graphics package.

Comment: Oh, fascinating. Is that also true for Arabic when it's not written entirely linearly?

Comment: @Dr.JohnnyMohawk: Can you provide an example? Arabic is supported in TeX; I'm sure it adheres to some linear format.

Comment: Google Arabic calligraphy: https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1859&bih=1040&q=arabic+calligraphy&oq=arabic+cal&gs_l=img.3.0.0l10.962.5368.0.7225.18.13.4.1.1.0.155.1183.5j6.11.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..2.16.1198.BnP2x0qYR_M It's sometimes linear, but not usually.

Comment: @Dr.JohnnyMohawk: That's not true Arabic, but rather [calligraphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calligraphy) - "a visual art related to writing". In general, [Arabic is linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic).